# Debugger fails to compile in Ruby

Tags: ruby, debugging, rubygems, bundler

Ruby 2.2.2 on Ubuntu
I have been following the saasbook tutorial on Rails and am getting to grips with the workflow.

I am confused about debugger which some sources says us now 'included' post Ruby version 2. It fails to compile on the example projects and many people have the same issue.

I have found that any bundle install that I try to do with the examples. (see [here](https://github.com/saasbook/courseware/wiki)) (possibly after a bundle update) will fail on trying to 'gem install debugger -v '1.6.x''.

I have found that by commenting out the debugger line in the Gemfile will get me around this hurdle and upon firing up the Rails server, everything seems to work. I also have to change the Ruby version to my current one (2.2.2).

I am assuming that I am working with pre version 2 Ruby examples and this is good to do post version 2.

Am I correct? What has happened to the debugger post version 2?

Comment: I have added this question because a lt of people (on Google) seem to have an issue with debugger failing to compile. I think this maybe because it is no longer a problem and bundle update does not solve the issue.
I have tried to make the question specific but if the consensus is to close with no comment then so be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debugger gem is not supported on Ruby 1.9. See the debugger readme on GitHub [here](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger). If you need a command line debugger for newer versions of Ruby you can use [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug).

You can use the basic built in debugger if you prefer. Simply put `require 'debug'` anywhere in your source code and the Ruby interpretor will stop at that point and allow you to inspect variables etc. You do not need to install or add any additional gems to your Gemfile to use this as it is built in. See the built in debugger documentation [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/debug/rdoc/DEBUGGER__.html)

Comment: Thank you. So am I correct that when building ruby apps using bundle install, the debugger had been included from earlier Rubys and needed commenting out? Bundle update having failed to remove the debugger requirement.

Comment: It possible it was installed earlier. If you are using ruby 2 and you have a line that looks something like `gem 'debugger'` in your Gemfile you should probably remove it.

Comment: Thanks. I think a LOT of people are seeing this issue trying to use  1.x.x examples when learning stuff about rails.